# Android open URL intent in javascript interface method

Tags: javascript, android, android-activity, android-webview, activitynotfoundexception

I have a webview in my app; I added a `JavascriptInterface` for that. 
In JavaScript interface implementation I have a method for opening URL in new intent but I received an ActivityNotFoundException

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public void openUrl(String url) {
        try
        {         
          Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
          localIntent.addFlags(268435456);
          localIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
          Context.startActivity(localIntent);         
          return;
        }
        catch (Exception localException)
        {

        }

    }
```

The given error is:

```
exception while trying to open intent: http://google.com
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=google.com flg=0x10000000 pkg=null }
```

Any ideas as to what the problem is?

Comment: did you check your AndroidManifest.xml, see if that activity is added to it?  <activity
            android:name=" xxx"
            android:label="xxx" >
        </activity>

Comment: @dshun all activities are added in AndroidManifest.xml , but this method is on a non-activity class